# Change color of one line of a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-text-color

I want make a `ListView` that have some elements with the `WHITE` text color and some other elements with the `BLACK` text color.

Here is my code for now:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =
new ArrayAdapter<String>(My_Activity.this, R.layout.row_lay, R.id.textViewList, myarray);
listLead.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

I can modify the TextColor of my `R.layout.row_lay` but this change the color for all the Line of my ListView. How can I do for example one line a color and the other another one?
Is possible to achieve that ? Different TextColor in the same ListView?

If yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have override the `getView` method of the `ArrayAdapter`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(My_Activity.this, R.layout.row_lay, R.id.textViewList, myarray) { 

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    //your condition logic
    v.setBackgroundColor(yourColor);

    return v;
    }
};
```

Comment: Because of view recycling it has to be set back to the original colors when the condition is not met as well, otherwise when you scroll, they all become colored as if they meet the special condition.

Comment: @NameSpace, That's right, you'd have to set it back. But I don't know OP's condition logic that's why I commented as `//your condition logic` OP asked how to change the color of one row, and this is how you do it.

Comment: I'm trying your answer but got an error, question uploaded.

Comment: @GMX Because you're not using a custom adapter, you'll have to write that inline where you declare your adapter. Check my updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom Adapter class that extends `ArrayAdapter`, and override `getView` like so:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_textview_id);
    if (position == whiteColoredPosition){
        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else {
        text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    return v;
}
```

Where `R.id.my_textview_id` is the ID of your `TextView` and `whiteColoredPosition` is the position in the ListView containing the TextView you want to be white.